# How can i add thumbnails to search results in the Add Product modal (Woocommerce Admin)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, modal-dialog

[image]

I'm trying to update the functionality of the search in the Add Products modal (when creating a new order in the WooCommerce Admin area) so that the thumbnail for each product in the search results is also displayed.

How would I go about doing this ? Is there an existing function I can hook into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet, but you'd need to add some styling

```
add_filter('woocommerce_json_search_found_products', 'test_function_products_image');

function test_function_products_image($products){
    foreach($products as $key => $name){
        $product = wc_get_product($key);
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' )[0];
        if($src){
            $image = '<img class="list-image" src="'. $src . '">';
            $products[$key] = $image . $products[$key];
        }
    }
    return $products;
}
```